Understanding the coefficients of highly correlated features in generalized linear models
I am trying to fit a generalized linear model, for simplicity assume that is a linear regression. I have a bunch of features and I fitted a linear model to it, the feature x9 is not significant (for example the t-statistic is small).
                         OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.518
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.507
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     46.27
Date:                Wed, 08 Mar 2017   Prob (F-statistic):           3.83e-62
Time:                        10:08:24   Log-Likelihood:                -2386.0
No. Observations:                 442   AIC:                             4794.
Df Residuals:                     431   BIC:                             4839.
Df Model:                          10                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        152.1335      2.576     59.061      0.000     147.071     157.196
x1           -10.0122     59.749     -0.168      0.867    -127.448     107.424
x2          -239.8191     61.222     -3.917      0.000    -360.151    -119.488
x3           519.8398     66.534      7.813      0.000     389.069     650.610
x4           324.3904     65.422      4.958      0.000     195.805     452.976
x5          -792.1842    416.684     -1.901      0.058   -1611.169      26.801
x6           476.7458    339.035      1.406      0.160    -189.621    1143.113
x7           101.0446    212.533      0.475      0.635    -316.685     518.774
x8           177.0642    161.476      1.097      0.273    -140.313     494.442
x9             1.2793      1.902      0.070      0.906       0.409       2.150
==============================================================================

But then when I add another feature x10 to it, suddenly both x9 and x10 become significant, both have huge coefficients but have opposite sign, and R^2 becomes higher, how should I interpret this?
                         OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.520
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.509
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     46.27
Date:                Wed, 08 Mar 2017   Prob (F-statistic):           3.81e-62
Time:                        10:08:24   Log-Likelihood:                -2380.0
No. Observations:                 442   AIC:                             4781.
Df Residuals:                     431   BIC:                             4831.
Df Model:                          10                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        152.1335      2.576     59.061      0.000     147.071     157.196
x1           -10.0122     59.749     -0.168      0.867    -127.448     107.424
x2          -239.8191     61.222     -3.917      0.000    -360.151    -119.488
x3           519.8398     66.534      7.813      0.000     389.069     650.610
x4           324.3904     65.422      4.958      0.000     195.805     452.976
x5          -792.1842    416.684     -1.901      0.058   -1611.169      26.801
x6           476.7458    339.035      1.406      0.160    -189.621    1143.113
x7           101.0446    212.533      0.475      0.635    -316.685     518.774
x8           177.0642    161.476      1.097      0.273    -140.313     494.442
x9          5751.2793   5171.902      4.370      0.950    5413.409    5189.150
x10        -7867.6254  -7765.984      1.025      0.906   -9862.065   -6197.316
==============================================================================


That the magnitude of the coefficient for x9 changes so drastically, and that x10 has  a coefficient of similar magnitude and opposite sign is a hint to me that these are very highly correlated.  I would reckon that a unit change in x9 does not lead to a 5751 change in the outcome because x9 rarely changes without x10 also changing, which would cancel out part of the observed ceterius paribus effect.
That the R squared increases when you add a variable is also unsurprising to me.  That is known to be a property of R squared since the residual variance always decreases with more variables added to the model.

just did a test and found out they are indeed highly correlated, thank that's why the result is so odd, thanks a lot!
